# NHibernate: could not instantiate CacheProvider?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, .net-4.0, webforms

I am new to NHibernate and am working on an ASP.NET webforms project that references another assembly that uses NHibernate.  I can make calls to methods that use NHibernate on my local copy, but when I publish the project to the test server, I get this:

`could not instantiate CacheProvider: NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache`

I apologize for the vague nature of this question, but, given what little I know about NHibernate at this point, it's all I can really offer.  Perhaps a light might come on for some gurus out there who caught on to the fact that it works when debugging locally, but not when published.

If more info is needed on this in order to provide an answer, just let me know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you confirmed that the published project includes `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.dll` in the bin folder?  If not, try adding that as a reference and republishing.  Sounds like it just can't find the dll.

Comment: This was the issue.  I had the DLL in my local bin folder, but it wasn't added as a reference, so it didn't copy along with the publish.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to deploy the nh syscache assembly with the project.